# Error requiring local pachage through composer

Tags: composer-php

I have two symfony4 applications offer/management and offer/fetcher and for now, I want to use offer/management as the main project and offer/fetcher as a local dependency of offer/management. So I create separate directories:

1. offer-management with own composer.json
2. offer-fetcher with own composer.json

Here is a composer.json for offer/fetcher:

```
{
    "name": "offer/fetcher",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/messenger": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppOffersFetcher\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppOffersFetcher\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a composer.json for offer/management:

```
{
    "name": "offer/management",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../offer-fetcher"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "offer/fetcher": "^1.0",
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/messenger": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "OfferManagement\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "OfferManagement\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "security-checker security:check": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

and the error when I run composer install from offer-management is:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for offer/management dev-master -> satisfiable by offer/management[dev-master].
    - don't install offer/fetcher 1.0.0|remove offer/management dev-master
    - Installation request for offer/fetcher ^1.0 -> satisfiable by offer/fetcher[1.0.0].
```

Comment: You have some typos in your `composer.json` - `offers/fetcher` vs `offer/fetcher`.

Comment: this typo is unrelated as I'm using fake names here and made a typo only creating this question. I already update a question to fix the typo